# Does filesink store GstMeta to file?

Tags: c, gstreamer

I am trying, using GStreamer in c, to add metadata to some recording and then read the recording back along with the metadata.

To do so, i am implementing GstMeta. I copied the exact example from the doc (the implementation is added at the end of the question): https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/plugin-development/advanced/allocation.html?gi-language=c#gstmeta.
See also [GstMeta](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/gstreamer/gstmeta.html?gi-language=c).

Adding/Retrieving the GstMeta within the same pipeline works (see the "queueProbe" in the encoding pipeline).
But retrieving the same GstMeta from the recorded file doesn't work (in the "getMeta" probe, meta is null).

Here is the minimal reproduction. In short:

- The encoding pipeline : videotestsrc ! queue ! filesink
  The src pad of the source element is probbed to add the GstMeta
  and the queue is probbed to get the GstMeta in the encoding pipeline.
- The decoding pipeline : filesrc ! rawvideoparse ! autovideosink
  The src pad of the parser is probbed to read the GstMeta.

**encode.c**

```
#include <gst/gst.h>
#include <gst/gstmeta.h>
#include "my-example-meta.h"

GstPadProbeReturn addMeta(GstPad *pad, GstPadProbeInfo *info, gpointer *data) {
    GstBuffer *buffer = GST_PAD_PROBE_INFO_BUFFER(info);
    gst_buffer_add_my_example_meta(buffer,2,"john");
    return GST_PAD_PROBE_OK;
}

GstPadProbeReturn queueProbe(GstPad *pad, GstPadProbeInfo *info, gpointer *data) {
    GstBuffer *buffer = GST_PAD_PROBE_INFO_BUFFER(info);
    MyExampleMeta *meta;
    meta=gst_buffer_get_my_example_meta(buffer);
    g_print("%d\n",meta->age);
    return GST_PAD_PROBE_OK;
}

int main(){
    gst_init(NULL,NULL);
    GstElement *src, *queue, *sink;
    GstElement *pipeline;
    src=gst_element_factory_make("videotestsrc",NULL);
    queue=gst_element_factory_make("queue",NULL);
    sink=gst_element_factory_make("filesink",NULL);
    pipeline=gst_pipeline_new("pipeline");

    g_object_set(src, "is-live", TRUE, NULL);
    g_object_set(sink, "location", "test", NULL);

    gst_bin_add_many(GST_BIN(pipeline),src,queue,sink,NULL);
    if(!gst_element_link_many(src,queue, sink, NULL))
    {
        g_print("Elements not linked.\n");
    }

    gst_pad_add_probe (gst_element_get_static_pad (src, "src"), GST_PAD_PROBE_TYPE_BUFFER,
    (GstPadProbeCallback) addMeta, NULL, NULL);

    gst_pad_add_probe (gst_element_get_static_pad (queue, "src"), GST_PAD_PROBE_TYPE_BUFFER,
    (GstPadProbeCallback) queueProbe, NULL, NULL);
    
    gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
    g_usleep(2 * 1000000);
    gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
}
```

**decode.c**

```
#include <gst/gst.h>
#include <gst/gstmeta.h>
#include "my-example-meta.h"

GstPadProbeReturn getMeta(GstPad *pad, GstPadProbeInfo *info, gpointer *data) {
    GstBuffer *buffer = GST_PAD_PROBE_INFO_BUFFER(info);

    MyExampleMeta *meta;
    meta=gst_buffer_get_my_example_meta(buffer);

    //Assert that the meta api was inialized correctly
    const GstMetaInfo* metaInfo = my_example_meta_get_info();
    const gchar *const *array = gst_meta_api_type_get_tags(metaInfo->api);
    for (int i = 0; array[i] != NULL; i++) {
        g_print("%s\t", array[i]);
    }

    if(!meta) g_print("No meta\n");
    else g_print("%d\n",meta->age);

    return GST_PAD_PROBE_OK;
}

int main(){
    gst_init(NULL,NULL);
    GstElement *src,*parser, *sink;
    GstElement *pipeline;
    src=gst_element_factory_make("filesrc",NULL);
    parser=gst_element_factory_make("rawvideoparse",NULL);
    sink=gst_element_factory_make("autovideosink",NULL);
    pipeline=gst_pipeline_new("pipeline");

    g_object_set(src, "location", "test", NULL);

    gst_bin_add_many(GST_BIN(pipeline),src,parser,sink,NULL);
    if(!gst_element_link_many(src, parser, sink, NULL))
    {
        g_print("link failed\n");
    }

    gst_pad_add_probe (gst_element_get_static_pad(parser,"src"), GST_PAD_PROBE_TYPE_BUFFER,
    (GstPadProbeCallback) getMeta, NULL, NULL);
    
    gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
    g_usleep(5 * 1000000);
    gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
}
```

**Compile**

```
gcc -o encode encode.c my-example-meta.c ` pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-1.0 gstreamer-app-1.0 `
```

```
gcc -o decode decode.c my-example-meta.c ` pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-1.0 gstreamer-app-1.0 `
```

**Run**
`./encode`
`./decode`

**Output**

- encode:
  a series of '2', indicating a correct read of the GstMeta.
- decode:
  a series of 'foo  bar  No meta', indicating a corect initialization but no actual metadata.

**Expected output**
I expect the GstMeta to be stored alongside buffer data into the file.
In the decoding side, I expect '2' instead of 'No meta'.
I struggle to determine if the metadata really isn't present in the file (which would mean that GstMeta is forgotten in the filesink element) or if the metadata is present in the file but isn't interpreted correctly.

I added breakpoints to every function in `my-example-meta.c`, and the functions are called in the expected order.

**my-example-meta.h**

```
#include <gst/gst.h>

typedef struct _MyExampleMeta MyExampleMeta;

struct _MyExampleMeta {
  GstMeta       meta;

  gint          age;
  gchar        *name;
};

GType my_example_meta_api_get_type (void);
#define MY_EXAMPLE_META_API_TYPE (my_example_meta_api_get_type())

#define gst_buffer_get_my_example_meta(b) \
  ((MyExampleMeta*)gst_buffer_get_meta((b),MY_EXAMPLE_META_API_TYPE))

/* implementation */
const GstMetaInfo *my_example_meta_get_info (void);
#define MY_EXAMPLE_META_INFO (my_example_meta_get_info())

MyExampleMeta * gst_buffer_add_my_example_meta (GstBuffer      *buffer,
                                                gint            age,
                                                const gchar    *name);
```

**my-example-meta.c**

```
#include "my-example-meta.h"

GType
my_example_meta_api_get_type (void)
{
  static GType type;
  static const gchar *tags[] = { "foo", "bar", NULL };

  if (g_once_init_enter (&type)) {
    GType _type = gst_meta_api_type_register ("MyExampleMetaAPI", tags);
    g_once_init_leave (&type, _type);
  }
  return type;
}

static gboolean
my_example_meta_init (GstMeta * meta, gpointer params, GstBuffer * buffer)
{
  MyExampleMeta *emeta = (MyExampleMeta *) meta;

  emeta->age = 0;
  emeta->name = NULL;

  return TRUE;
}

static gboolean
my_example_meta_transform (GstBuffer * transbuf, GstMeta * meta,
    GstBuffer * buffer, GQuark type, gpointer data)
{
  MyExampleMeta *emeta = (MyExampleMeta *) meta;

  /* we always copy no matter what transform */
  gst_buffer_add_my_example_meta (transbuf, emeta->age, emeta->name);

  return TRUE;
}

static void
my_example_meta_free (GstMeta * meta, GstBuffer * buffer)
{
  MyExampleMeta *emeta = (MyExampleMeta *) meta;

  g_free (emeta->name);
  emeta->name = NULL;
}

const GstMetaInfo *
my_example_meta_get_info (void)
{
  static const GstMetaInfo *meta_info = NULL;

  if (g_once_init_enter (&meta_info)) {
    const GstMetaInfo *mi = gst_meta_register (MY_EXAMPLE_META_API_TYPE,
        "MyExampleMeta",
        sizeof (MyExampleMeta),
        my_example_meta_init,
        my_example_meta_free,
        my_example_meta_transform);
    g_once_init_leave (&meta_info, mi);
  }
  return meta_info;
}

MyExampleMeta *
gst_buffer_add_my_example_meta (GstBuffer   *buffer,
                                gint         age,
                                const gchar *name)
{
  MyExampleMeta *meta;

  g_return_val_if_fail (GST_IS_BUFFER (buffer), NULL);

  meta = (MyExampleMeta *) gst_buffer_add_meta (buffer,
      MY_EXAMPLE_META_INFO, NULL);

  meta->age = age;
  meta->name = g_strdup (name);

  return meta;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meta is not saved to disk by the filesink. Here are some alternatives:

- Serialize the meta and manually append it as part of the buffer content. You'll need to also manually load it at the decoder side.
- Use a container to store custom information. For example EXIF allows you to add custom information in the `MakerNote` and `UserComment` tags.
- H264 and H265 allows you to add custom information as SEI NAL units. This is a bit more complex.